# Multiple View Model

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I think I need to have multiple view models.

I have never really understood MVC and have been using scaffolding tools. What i do know is databases.

```
public class Customer:BaseEntity
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public Addresses.Address Address { get; set; }
    public Contacts.Contact Contact { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Comments.Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Address:BaseEntity
{
    public string NoName { get; set; }
    public string AddressL1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressL2 { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
}

public class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
public class Comment:BaseEntity
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public Jobs.Job Job { get; set; }
    public Users.ApplicationUser AppUser { get; set; }
}
```

I need to be able to display Customer, Address, Contact and loop through all Comments to display in a grid.

I am sure I am missing something really simple.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have any other properties that you would like to display, I do not see a reason for creating an extra class. So you can pass the Customer class itself to the View.

But if you do have other fields that you would like to use in the view, you can create a View Model Class that has the Customer class as one of its properties.

```
public class CustomerVM {
  public Customer Customer { get; set; }
  public OtherProperty Property { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the controller assign the customer to the View Model and pass it to the view.

```
var customer = fetchCustomer();
CustomerVM vm = new CustomerVM {
   Customer = customer,
   OtherProperty = otherProperty
};

return View(vm);
```

In the view you can access and display the properties

```
@model CustomerVM

@Model.Customer.Address.NoName // and so fourth for other properties
```